# Time difference between two date's

Tags: zend-framework

I'm sure this is easy but it has had me stumped for ages.
I need to compare two dates and only return the hours and minutes difference.
Thanks for any ideas :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the unix timestamp of them both and subtract the earlier from the later.  The result will be the number of seconds that has passed between the two dates.

Comment: thanks, knew it would be simple had been working with ISO and getting a headache.